# PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type, can't show DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Encountered this problem several times, that SQL Developer can't show DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE despite already turning serveroutput on and Dbms Output turned on from View toolbar

```
set serveroutput on;
accept p_angka prompt 'Input Number : ';

declare
    a integer;
    b integer :=&p_angka;

begin
    dbms_output.put_line('---ODD NUMBER---');
    for a in 1..b loop
        if (a mod 2) then
            dbms_output.put_line(a);
        end if;
    end loop;
end;
```

Console succesfully asking for input but can't show the desired output anywhere with

```
ORA-06550: line 8, column 12:
PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
ORA-06550: line 8, column 9: error
```

Comment: In Oracle, `mod` is a function, not an operator. `mod(a, 2)` rather than `a mod 2` - as Popeye already explained in his answer. Moreover, this is not C - you can't use an arithmetic expression and expect it to be converted implicitly to Boolean. You must explicitly compare your "mod" to 0 or 1, also as Popeye showed.

Comment: `a mod 2` is valid in PL/SQL as well as the conventional `mod()` function from SQL.

Comment: The reason you're not seeing dbms_output is that PL/SQL is a compiled language, and due to the syntax error at line 8 (the `if` condition) it is not valid and never starts. Even if it did, the dbms_output call is after the line with the error.

Comment: By the way, C type languages use brackets for `if` conditions e.g. `if (a > b) do_something`. PL/SQL's `if` conditions are instead terminated by the `then` keyword, e.g. `if a > b then do_something`.

Answer (score 2):

I think there are several mistakes in your code which is mentioned inline in the following code:

```
set serveroutput on;
-- accept p_angka prompt 'Input Number : '; -- not needed 
declare
--a integer; -- not needed
b integer := &p_angka;
begin
  dbms_output.put_line('---ODD NUMBER---');
  for a in 1..b loop
    if (mod(a,2) = 0) then -- mod function should be used like this
      dbms_output.put_line(a);
    end if;
  end loop;
end;
/
```

<kbd>[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4c26d5862ca2473de37c563d6499d23f)</kbd> with constant value for b.

Comment: You marked the ACCEPT command as "not needed". Do you know what that command does? The OP used it exactly as intended; your comment suggests you are not familiar with that command and with how it is used.